# Existence of a non-zero homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

In the proof of Maschke theorem (Theorem 6.1, Page 83, of the book entitled "A first course of noncommutative rings" by T. Y. Lam), a nonzero $R$-homomorphism is used. In fact, the homomorphism extends to $RG$-homomorphism.

Now a question comes to my mind that:

Let $M$ and $N$ be two  left $RG$-modules and let $G$ be a
finite group with $|G|^{-1}\in R$. Assume that $f: M\longrightarrow N$ is a nonzero $R$-homomorphism (or suppose isomorphism for convenience).

Can we conclude that $\psi: M\longrightarrow N,~~\psi(x)=|G|^{-1}\sum_{h\in G}h^{-1}f(hx)$
is a nonzero $RG$-homomorphism?

I have no idea about that. It is definitely right for all $R$-semisimple modules. Can anything else be said about this?

Comment: @Shaun I made changes. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. The map $\psi$ you provide is clearly $G$-invariant, but for distinct irreducible isomorphism types of $G$-modules, by Schur's lemma, there are no nonzero homomorphisms. The easiest example of this comes with $R=\mathbb R$, $G=\mathbb Z/(2)$, $M$ being $R$ with the trivial action, and $N$ being $R$ with the action by multiplication by $-1$.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, $\psi(gx)=g\psi(x)$

Comment: @AshwinTrisal are $M$ and $N$ simple $R$-modules in your example?

Comment: @reuns \psi(gx)=|G|^{-1}\sum_{h\in G}h^{-1}f(hgx)\overset{hg=t\in G}{=}~
 |G|^{-1}\sum_{t\in G}gt^{-1}f(tx)=
 |G|^{-1}g\sum_{t\in G}t^{-1}f(tx)=g|G|^{-1}\sum_{t\in G}t^{-1}f(tx)=g\psi(x)

Comment: Ah sorry I thought you wanted to show that $\psi$ is a $RG$-module map, I missed the *non-zero*.

Comment: @AshwinTrisal Let M=$K\oplus N$ as an $R$-module and $f:=p:M\longrightarrow N$ be the canonical $R$-homomorphism. Then $\psi$ is not zero!